# USA F-4 family visa and immigration

Tags: us-citizens, application-status

My priority date is June 2007.  My case status is currently *case is at NVC.*

How much more time will it take for our visas? My son was 14 in June 2007.  He is now 25 years old.  What will happen when the file is opened if my son is 26 or more?  Will he be eligible or not?  How much time is left?

I dont know when it's been approved. I received a letter with information about my case and case number:

> Case Number: < deleted personal details >,...........
>
> Petitioner's Name: < deleted personal details > ......
>
> Principal Applicant's Name: < deleted personal details >,.......
>
> Preference Category: F4
>
> Your Priority Date: 18Jun2007
>
> Foreign State Chargeability: PAKISTAN

Comment: When was your I-130 approved?

Comment: i dont know when its approved. i received leter and info about my case and case number
Case Number: ISL2010...........
Petitioner's Name: WAHEED, ......
Principal Applicant's Name: BEGUM,.......
Preference Category: F4
Your Priority Date: 18Jun2007
Foreign State Chargeability: PAKISTAN
this info on letter

Comment: The I-130 approval notice will have the approval date.

Comment: mean june 2007 is our approval date?

Comment: No. You said the priority date is June 2007. The priority date is the date the I-130 was filed.